# How to force refresh Chrome, Safari

Tags: javascript, styles, refresh

In my site, I have a process to download a JSON data. During this time, I displayed in full screen a div with a spin.
With FF and IE, the div is visible before to start the download, but not with Chrome and Safari.

JSFiddle link here : https://jsfiddle.net/r6s0cr31/4/, the background color doesn't change on Chrome and Safari, for IE & FF the background-color change before.

```
$('#mapLoading').show();
$.ajaxSetup({async: false});
$.getJSON("https://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/0,40;0,42?overview=full&alternatives=true&steps=true",
   function( response ) {

   }
)
$('#mapLoading').hide();
```

If I place a stop point in console(chrome) before getJSON, I can see that the div is right displayed.
I tried to do that in pure JS without JQuery but the problem seems to be the same.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using sync (which freeze the browser), using async and hide it after get the response will solve the problem:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $('#mapLoading').show();
    $.getJSON("https://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/0,40;0,42?overview=full&alternatives=true&steps=true")
    .then(function(response){
        $('#mapLoading').hide();
    })    
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r6s0cr31/7/

Answer (score 1):

You are using a deprecated async false irrelevant to that in chrome code freezes before ajax call a timeout will solve the problem

```
 setTimeout(function () {
$.ajaxSetup({async: false});
$.getJSON("https://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/0,40;0,42?overview=full&alternatives=true&steps=true",
   function( response ) {

   }
)
$('#mapLoading').hide();
}, 20);
```

In your case the code gets executed but its seen after callback

Working fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/r6s0cr31/5/

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Chrome and Safari are running the function first an rerendering page content after it's execution. Therefore no change is seen.

As Andy Chen wrote already, it's better to go asynchronous even in terms of user experience:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $('#mapLoading').show();
    $.getJSON("https://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/0,40;0,42?overview=full&alternatives=true&steps=true",
       function( response ) {

         /* ...code here... */
         $('#mapLoading').hide();
       }
    )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply, I learned :
- no asynchrous request freeze Chrome & Safari
- Chrome and Safari run the function first and update the page design after.

Thanks again